# SnowFlake - How to return the column that the least function value came from?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, min

I am doing a Snowflake query where I get RANK from each column.
Output below:

```
| Rank_A   | Rank B   |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1        | 3        |
| 2        | 4        |
| 5        | 4        |
```

Then I do the LEAST function to get the Minimum across those columns
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/least.html

Output below:

```
| Rank_A   | Rank B   | LEAST    | 
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1        | 3        | 1        |
| 2        | 4        | 2        |
| 5        | 4        | 4        |
```

Lastly, (This is where I am not sure of) How can I make another column that returns what column the Least function came from - so what I am trying to return in this new column is like so:

Expected output below:

```
| Rank_A   | Rank B   | LEAST    | Column Name of Least Value |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------------------------- |
| 1        | 3        | 1        | Rank_A                     |  
| 2        | 4        | 2        | Rank_A                     |
| 5        | 4        | 4        | Rank_B                     |
```

I have no idea how I would go about this?  any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

I do not know where to begin.  I was contemplating doing this all in python before ingesting the data table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [DECODE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/decode.html) to get the **first** `LEAST` value column name:

```
SELECT *
    ,LEAST(Rank_A, Rank_B)
    ,DECODE(LEAST(Rank_A, Rank_B),
            Rank_A, 'Rank_A',
            Rank_B, 'Rank_B') AS column_name
FROM tab;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! perfect solution as well much cleaner than the one below.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a `CASE` expression along with the `LEAST()` function:

```sql
SELECT
    RANK_A,
    RANK_B,
    LEAST(Rank_A, Rank_B) AS LEAST,
    CASE WHEN RANK_A = LEAST(Rank_A, Rank_B)
         THEN 'RANK_A' ELSE 'RANK_B' END AS LEAST_VALUE
FROM yourTable;
```

In the event that `RANK_A` and `RANK_B` have the same value, the above query would arbitrarily return `RANK_A` as the column with the least value.